# Enable scroll for a div but lock it for another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

this is my website http://www.yarrutfranken.com/

if you press the **'plus'** button on the homepage my contact information will show up. But I can not scroll on the black page. (try making window smaller then you will see).

There's some text falling off when you are on a 11" or 13" laptop.

so wrap up:

- **need scroll on black information page**
- **if information page is active scroll must be blocked on 'homepage'.**

please help me.

ps: i'm not a hero in javascript or other stuff. Just;

- *html*
- *css*
- *jquery*

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow-y: auto;` to your `#actinfo` css rule in order to allow it to scroll if the content is higher than the element's height.

```
#actinfo {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4000;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: lol thanks man, looks so simple :p simply hadn't thought of that.

Comment: no problem, glad to help. Set it to auto in order to avoid having the scrollbar if the content is not tall enough to be scrolled. Auto will only show the scrollbar if it has scroll :)

Comment: ^^right answer. On a side note your might want to set `overflow-x: hidden;` so you don't get that ugly horizontal scrollbar